# How to make wevtutil tool return results in UTF-8 format?

Tags: windows, unicode, event-log, utf-8

I'm writing a script that requires me to look up a specific event in the Windows Event Log using [`wevtutil`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732848.aspx) tool. The command line goes as such:

```
wevtutil qe System /q:"*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter']]]" /rd:true /c:1 /f:text
```

but its output is truncated to ANSI encoding and I may lose some non-English characters.

Having looked through [its documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732848.aspx), I found that there's `/l:` parameter that allows to specify a locale. So I tried this:

```
wevtutil qe System /q:"*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter']]]" /rd:true /c:1 /f:text /l:utf-8
```

but it gives me:

> LCID utf-8 cannot be found. The parameter is incorrect.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 is not a locale, but a form of character encoding. For valid locales, see [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx)

From your link, it looks like you simply need /uni:true

Comment: Thank you. I managed to miss it. Although that parameter doesn't use UTF-8. It's more like UTF-16

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, it should allow all the characters you need, although may take up a bit more more space in doing so. You could always convert back from UTF-16 to UTF-8 afterwards if you are certain you're not using any characters from UTF-16.